# How to resolve a syntax-checker error on TypeScript in Visual Studio

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display an array using Angular and TypeScript, and I am getting an error I do not understand.

When I move my cursor to the Goal that red lined it shows this:

> Type '{ id: number; name: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Goal': id, name

Image:

[image]

Visual Studio shows a red line on Goal saying this:

> Type '{ id: number; name: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Goal': id, name

Can any coder show me exactly what to do?

Comment: Titles in any help forum or Q&A system should always succinctly describe what the problem is. Do not add "please help me" or other pleading - that does not help readers.

Comment: In the future, please post your code as text, not images. Images should only supplement your question and not be necessary to understand it, for a variety of reasons (for example, they can't be searched for and screen readers can't parse them).

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to assign an array of `Goal` to a property of type `Goal` (singular). Change the type of the `Goal` property to `Goal[]`.

```
goals: Goal[] = [
  { id: 1, name: '...' },
  { id: 2, name: '...' },
  ...
];
```